# How to include item's statistics in Collection on DSPace 6?

Tags: solr, statistics, dspace

I have a collection with 15 documents, manually I added the views of each items anfd the total was 23.000~ but when I view the statistics of the colecction I get 3.200~. When viewing the statistics of a collection in DSpace 6 I only get the views the collection has gotten but it doesn't add the views the items of that collection has gotten.

How can I add each item's statistics into the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DSpace Usage Statistics for a Collection or Community only display views of the Collection or Community landing page.  The total item views are not displayed in the user interface.

The question can be answered by querying the Solr repository within DSpace.  We have built an internal reporting tool that computes these usage numbers.

#### All item views

```
type:2
```

#### All item views for a collection

*You can get the item uuid from the database or from the url of the item edit page.*

```
q=type:2 AND owningColl:59f3a497-9e82-4100-ba9a-e00cff04ec43
```

#### All item views for a community

```
q=type:2 AND owningComm:59f3a497-9e82-4100-ba9a-e00cff04ec43
```

#### All item views for a community for the last 12 months

```
q=type:2 AND owningComm:59f3a497-9e82-4100-ba9a-e00cff04ec43
facet.date=time
facet.date.start=NOW/MONTH/DAY-12MONTHS
facet.date.end=NOW/MONTH/DAY+1MONTH
facet.date.gap=+1MONTH
```

#### More information

I have a tutorial on using Solr with DSpace here: https://github.com/terrywbrady/TutorialSolrAdmin